# Preserve line breaks in HTML,JAVA,Spring

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, line-breaks

i have a web application built with HTML(front-end),java(server-side)
and i have a textarea when posting some data with line breaks (pressing enter after a word)
the line breaks are not reserved (the data appears next to each other with no line breaks)
how to preserve the line breaks ?, note that i am not using the  tag when displaying (have to)

i am using the code server side to convert new lines into br

```
public String saveLineBreaks(String text) {
        return text.replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
    }
```

but it doesn't work properly

Comment: question is not clear. give it us with example with code

Comment: question has been edited

Comment: don't use replaceAll, that's the regex version. Use replace(), you just want dumb string replacements.

Comment: i am using replaceAll because the text may contain more than one new line

Comment: or you can try to formulate the regex better by escaping the `\n` with an extra backslash.

Comment: @sword101 that's irrelevant. read the javadocs of String.replace() and String.replaceAll(). They both replace all occurences, but the former replaces strings while the latter uses regular expressions: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29 , http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: @posdef no, regex understands line breaks without extra escaping, but it's the wrong tool for a simple string replacement

Comment: @seanizer: i see.. a matter of effectivity?

Comment: @posdef yes. as a rule: always use the simplest possible solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a wild guess, as I don't know what web framework you are using etc. but:

Text from a `<textarea>` will probably have line breaks (`\n`), but HTML will interpret them as whitespace. So on the java side, you need to do something like this:

```
String forOutput = input.replace("\n", "<br />\n");
```

However, in almost every imaginable web framework, there is some utility method that does this for you manually or automatically, so the question is to find the right one for you.

Comment: doesn't work for me, i tried like 10 other versions of this

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `\n` isn't the line delimiter. Try using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.