# How can I send code as a paremeter in a POST request and preserve formatting?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to send some code into this backend call I created which does some synytax highlighting using `pygments` and spits out some HTML.

## Sample input:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generatepotd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void generatePOTD(@RequestBody POTD problem) throws Exception {

    mailService.sendBulkEmail(problem);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/highlight", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String highlightTester(@RequestBody String programInput) {

    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
```

When I get this data into my function, it looks like this

```
code=%40Controller%0Apublic+class+TemplateController+%7B%0A%0A++++%40Autowired%0A++++private+TemplateGenerationService+tempGen%3B%0A%0A++++%40Autowired%0A++++private+MailService+mailService%3B%0A%0A++++private+static+final+Logger+log+%3D+LoggerFactory.getLogger%28AlgorithmController.class%29%3B%0A%0A++++%40RequestMapping%28value+%3D+%22%2Fgeneratepotd%22%2C+method+%3D+RequestMethod.POST%29%0A++++%40ResponseBody%0A++++public+v
```

## Input that works when I hardcode

```
data = "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    @RequestMapping(value = \"/generatepotd\", method = RequestMethod.POST)\n" +
        "    @ResponseBody\n" +
        "    public void generatePOTD(@RequestBody POTD problem) throws Exception {\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        mailService.sendBulkEmail(problem);\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    @RequestMapping(value = \"/highlight\", method = RequestMethod.POST)\n" +
        "    @ResponseBody\n" +
        "    public String highlightTester(@RequestBody String programInput) {\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();"
```

I want to pass some random Java code as a value in my post params.

## The problem

The data does not preserve formatting at all. The newlines disappear, all the content get smashed and the output is abysmal as a result.

This website does a good job of solving this problem: http://hilite.me/ However, I'm not sure how the information is being POST'ed without having formatting issues.

## Smashed Output When I Paste in Code (Outputs as single line)

```
<div style="background: #272822"><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%"><span style="color: #f8f8f2">code</span><span style="color: #f92672">=++++%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">40</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">Autowired</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">private</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">TemplateGenerationService</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">tempGen</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">3</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">B</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">40</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">Autowired</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">private</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">MailService</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">mailService</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">3</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">B</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">private</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">static</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">final</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">Logger</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">log</span><span style="color: #f92672">+%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">3</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">D</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">LoggerFactory</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">getLogger</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">28</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">AlgorithmController</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">class</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">29</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">3</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">B</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">40</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">RequestMapping</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">28</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">value</span><span style="color: #f92672">+%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">3</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">D</span><span style="color: #f92672">+%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">22</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">2</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">Fgeneratepotd</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">22</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">2</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">C</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">method</span><span style="color: #f92672">+%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">3</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">D</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">RequestMethod</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">POST</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">29</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">40</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">ResponseBody</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">public</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">void</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">generatePOTD</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">28</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">40</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">RequestBody</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">POTD</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">problem</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">29</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">throws</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #a6e22e">Exception</span><span style="color: #f92672">+%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">7</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">B</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++++++</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">mailService</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">sendBulkEmail</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">28</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">problem</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">29</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">3</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">B</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">7</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">D</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">40</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">RequestMapping</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">28</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">value</span><span style="color: #f92672">+%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">3</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">D</span><span style="color: #f92672">+%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">22</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">2</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">Fhighlight</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">22</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">2</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">C</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">method</span><span style="color: #f92672">+%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">3</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">D</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">RequestMethod</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">POST</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">29</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">40</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">ResponseBody</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">0</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">A</span><span style="color: #f92672">++++</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">public</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">String</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">highlightTester</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">28</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">40</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">RequestBody</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">String</span><span style="color: #f92672">+</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">programInput</span><span style="color: #f92672">%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">29</span><span style="color: #f92672">+%</span><span style="color: #ae81ff">7</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">B</span>
</pre></div>
```

## Desire output when formatting is preserved:

```
    <div style="background: #272822"><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%"><span style="color: #f92672">import</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;</span>
<span style="color: #f92672">import</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;</span>

<span style="color: #a6e22e">@Controller</span>
<span style="color: #f8f8f2">public</span> <span style="color: #66d9ef">class</span> <span style="color: #a6e22e">TemplateController</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">{</span>

    <span style="color: #a6e22e">@Autowired</span>
    <span style="color: #f8f8f2">private</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">TemplateGenerationService</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">tempGen;</span>

    <span style="color: #a6e22e">@Autowired</span>
    <span style="color: #f8f8f2">private</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">MailService</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">mailService;</span>

    <span style="color: #f8f8f2">private</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">static</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">final</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">Logger</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">log</span> <span style="color: #f92672">=</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">LoggerFactory</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">getLogger(AlgorithmController</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">class);</span>

    <span style="color: #a6e22e">@RequestMapping</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">(value</span> <span style="color: #f92672">=</span> <span style="color: #e6db74">&quot;/generatepotd&quot;</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">,</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">method</span> <span style="color: #f92672">=</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">RequestMethod</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">POST)</span>
    <span style="color: #a6e22e">@ResponseBody</span>
    <span style="color: #f8f8f2">public</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">void</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">generatePOTD(</span><span style="color: #a6e22e">@RequestBody</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">POTD</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">problem)</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">throws</span> <span style="color: #a6e22e">Exception</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">{</span>

        <span style="color: #f8f8f2">mailService</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">sendBulkEmail(problem);</span>
    <span style="color: #f8f8f2">}</span>

    <span style="color: #a6e22e">@RequestMapping</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">(value</span> <span style="color: #f92672">=</span> <span style="color: #e6db74">&quot;/highlight&quot;</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">,</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">method</span> <span style="color: #f92672">=</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">RequestMethod</span><span style="color: #f92672">.</span><span style="color: #f8f8f2">POST)</span>
    <span style="color: #a6e22e">@ResponseBody</span>
    <span style="color: #f8f8f2">public</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">String</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">highlightTester(</span><span style="color: #a6e22e">@RequestBody</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">String</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">programInput)</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">{</span>

        <span style="color: #f8f8f2">PythonInterpreter</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">interpreter</span> <span style="color: #f92672">=</span> <span style="color: #f8f8f2">new</span> <span style="color:
```

Comment: How are you posting this?  Is it like an HTML textarea or what?  Show an example of the post body.

Comment: Try to code the string value using Base64 this will preserve the format of the String and decode it after using base64

Comment: @ErrabiAyoub, POST data won't be URL encoded, so there should be no need to encode to base64

Comment: I'm pasting it in exactly as shown above into a url form encoded field in postman at the moment

Comment: After sending the HTML in Postman, where do you find that formatting is lost?

Comment: The way I know is that I can hardcode the input in my IDE (auto adds newlines, etc as a string) and it works fine. When I POST it, it gets interpreted poorly.

Comment: Nothing should be lost in a POST request, so I would expect `@RequestBody` arguments to be populated with correct input. Do you find that the white spaces are missing in the received argument itself?

Comment: I think that you're using resttemplate or jersey client that why I suggest the base 64 so you can use @consumes(mediatype.text_html)

Comment: The smashed output you pasted above, is it printed in IDE console or on a website in html format? If yes, then this maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776279/preserve-line-breaks-in-html-java-spring

Comment: @11thdimension updating the OP with the input that causes things to break and the input that causes things to work

Comment: I've posted the output as I see it in the function right after the request is sent.. It looks... weird

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat No, this isn't the problem

Comment: Are you preprocessing the HTML in Javascript before sending it to the web service? Because the string that you've posted `code=...` is URL encoded and has `+` for all `white spaces`

Comment: No, I'm pasting this directly from the code to postman. I'm sending Java code, not HTML. The HTML is the finalized output after everything has processed.

Comment: Where is your REST (POST) method which receives the code?

Comment: It's actually the one inside the "sample input" above